# Transfer big data to php server-script

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I´m creating a little IDE in Javascript on my webpage and I´m struggling at the concept of the saving process. For the beginning I want to save the whole code written in my IDE to be saved in a `.txt`.

So far I know how to pass values from client-JS to server-PHP with HTTP-request, but my case I basically have to transfer a very long string. From within the php script I want to create/manipulate a `.txt` to save the data outside of the root of the webserver.

So I was wondering if there is a good solution to pass a lot of data at once to my php running on the server.

Comment: you can send part of string and build it to file by php script

Comment: Define what *a lot of data means* using units we understand - kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes etc.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko alerady thought about this, but hope there was a better solution.

Comment: @Mjh Well it´s going to be a IDE for little Javascript projects, so like a few hundred lines. While probably I´m not going to save everything at once, but if this was possible it wouldn´t be bad.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're optimizing. HTTP is used to pass the data back and forth, even when you upload huge files, even when you download huge files. So, you have what, maybe 2 KB of data? If you wouldn't use HTTP, what would you use? WebSockets? Which are implemented over HTTP? :) No, there is no other way to "speak" to server, it's HTTP. But, what I'm curious about is - why do you think it's bad? What exactly bothers you with HTTP?

Comment: @Mjh well I guess you´re right, don´t actually really know what I was expecting, going to work at a solution with HTTP request now :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, the file creating/writeing/reading stuff is clear to me, I´m looking for a way to pass the text written in my IDE to php running on my backend. I think I hsouldn´t use a a HTTP request for this.

Comment: @FatTony then how would you pass the data if not over HTTP?

Comment: @Mjh Well thats exactly my question here, I´m pretty new to php and was curious if there is another way to pass data.